# Drawing bar graph with achartengine

Tags: android

I am trying to generate a bar chart using achartengine . Bu I am getting error.
And my code is :

```
public GraphicalView getGraph(String[] labels,double[] values){
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(null);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < labels.length ;i++){
            series.add(labels[i], values[i]);
        }
        XYSeries mSeries = series.toXYSeries();
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(mSeries);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.setChartTitle("Exa");

        SimpleSeriesRenderer sRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        sRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(sRenderer);
        GraphicalView v = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
        return v;
    }
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: you have error in code

Comment: Where can you explain it

Comment: I might, if you cn explain what your error is.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

There is another library available which is more simple than achartengine.  [HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/src)

[image]

Thank you

Comment: go to https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/overview  you can see download option on right hand side